# Left panel with dynamic items html

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, css, dynamic

I'm trying to build a simple web page that allows a user to add/remove items from a left panel menu as presented on screenshot below. How can I achieve that?

I have basic knowledge in `HTML/CSS` and `AngularJS`. So any simple trick would be great. Thanks in advance.

[Left panel with dynamic elements](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UKEyG.jpg)

Comment: Please share with us what you have already tried

Comment: How did you get a "+1" for such a question ?

Comment: U can use append() method from jQuery. If the user click on Add button you can call event click and append new node under the current parent.